# Dereferencing NULL pointer warning in C even it is assigned already

Tags: c, nullpointerexception, calloc

I am trying to implement a unit cache structure and use `calloc` method(dynamic allocation) to give it memory space. I used the type-defined `cache_unit` as the type of the pointer to receive casted return type from `calloc`. Normally after `calloc`, all the bits in the allocated area should be 0. However my output is like random numbers instead of 0 and there're two warning messages.

Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <cstdint>

int main() {
    typedef struct {
        bool enabled;
        uint8_t block[10];
        int access_time;
    } cache_unit;
    

    cache_unit* cache = (cache_unit*) calloc(2, sizeof(cache_unit));
    printf("%x ", *cache);

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the warning messages on printf:
[image]

Comment: With `#include <cstdint>`, sure this is C?

Comment: It is actually C, I previously tried C++ on the same file and forgot to delete the head files linkings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `printf("%x ", *cache);`, `"%x"` expects a matching `unsigned`, not a `cache_unit`.

Try

```
printf("%d\n", cache->access_time);
```

Comment: It returns 0. For enabled it gets the same result. However random number for block.

Comment: "However random number for block." --> Post the code that supports this claim.  It is likely incorrect.  Are you printing the content of `block[]` or some address?

Comment: ```printf("%d\n", cache->block);```. It should get the first byte of block.

Comment: "It should get the first byte of block." --> No. `cache->block` converts to the address of the first element of the array.   `"%d"` expects a matching `int`, not an address. To print the value of the array (1st 3 elements):  `printf("%d %d %d\n", cache->block[0], cache->block[1], cache->block[2]);`

Comment: And the name of array should not be pointing to the first byte of the array?

Comment: @ShawnXu No.  An array is an array, not a pointer.  In some contexts, `cache->block` converts to the address of the first element of the array.  With `printf("%d\n", cache->block);` Why use `"%d"` (which matches an `int`)  to print an address?  Why expect printing an address to print the data content of the array?

Comment: So why do ```printf("%d\n", cache->enabled);``` and ```printf("%d\n", cache->access_time);``` successfully print contents of the address? They are written in the same form.

Comment: @ShawnXu: `cache->block` is an array. When an array is used in an expression other than as the operand of `sizeof` or as the operand of unary `&` or as a string literal used to initialize an array, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. `cache->enabled` is not an array, so it is not automatically converted. `cache->access_time` is not an array, so it is not automatically converted. The rule is simple: An array is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, except as listed above. Other types of objects generally are not automatically converted.